# Sync iPod Touch's calendar to Google Calendar

Tags: ipod-touch, calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

**How can you sync your calendar of iPod Touch to Google Calendar?**

I have rarely internet connection at my iPod Touch.
It has my calendar as "offline". I cannot share it with my friends.

I would like to use "Google Calendar" in a offline mode such that I can more easily sync my calendar, every time my iPod is online.

So problems are

1. to sync iPod Touch's calendar to Google Calendar
2. to be able to use Google calendar offline in iPod touch
3. to put iPod sync Gcal every time it observes a network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you sync your iPod touch using Google Sync, it should work just this way for you. If it can not find an internet connection, it should keep a local copy of its last update on your Touch. when it finds one, it should sync whatever you entered on your iPod with Google.

You can find out more at http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I am now trying to get the internet for my iPod Touch to test your suggestions at the thread http://serverfault.com/questions/67424/to-set-up-dhcp-in-osx

Comment: Do you know why I cannot use the "Gmail" logo? I am not sure why I need to use the Microsoft protocol. Do you know why?

Comment: because of the iPhone/iPod OS, the Gmail setup is just for IMAP mail to easily do the config for you. Google's new 'sync' stuff for mail, contacts, and calendar all run off the Exchange protocol.